# hide iPhone address bar with 100% height

Tags: javascript, iphone, hide, onload, address-bar

Many posts on this, but not quite for my situation. My page has flexible dimensions set to 100% width and 100% height, so the typical on-load scroll function isn't working. Any thoughts or other solutions?

Thanks!

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:960px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    /mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !pageYOffset && !location.hash && setTimeout(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 1000);​
```

Comment: would 101% work with a scrollTo?

Comment: @Jess Likely not, but now we have the option of 100VH or minimal-ui

Answer (score 5):

This solution from Nate Smith helped me: [How to Hide the Address Bar in a Full Screen Iphone or Android Web App](http://blog.nateps.com/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-in-a-full-screen).

Here's the essential bit:

```
var page   = document.getElementById('page'),
    ua     = navigator.userAgent,
    iphone = ~ua.indexOf('iPhone') || ~ua.indexOf('iPod');

var setupScroll = window.onload = function() {
  // Start out by adding the height of the location bar to the width, so that
  // we can scroll past it
  if (ios) {
    // iOS reliably returns the innerWindow size for documentElement.clientHeight
    // but window.innerHeight is sometimes the wrong value after rotating
    // the orientation
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    // Only add extra padding to the height on iphone / ipod, since the ipad
    // browser doesn't scroll off the location bar.
    if (iphone && !fullscreen) height += 60;
    page.style.height = height + 'px';
  }
  // Scroll after a timeout, since iOS will scroll to the top of the page
  // after it fires the onload event
  setTimeout(scrollTo, 0, 0, 1);
};
```

For more details, check out his [blog post](http://blog.nateps.com/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-in-a-full-screen) or the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1172490).

Comment: what does the variable 'page' refer to?

Comment: Updated the code snippet to include definition of variable 'page'.

Comment: The link to the blog entry is dead. Also iOS has other browsers (most notably: chrome) that does not have the same header behaviour, so a "isSafari" check might come in handy.

Comment: What does `ios` refer to, it's not defined and gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this too. Initially I tried a CSS class (.stretch) defining 200% height and overflow visible, then toggling this on the HTML via script before and after the scrollTo. This doesn't work because the computed 100% height refers back to the available viewport dimensions minus all browser chrome (snapping the status bar back into place).

Eventually I had to request specific styles to apply dynamically via the DOM API. To add to your additional snippet:

```
var CSS = document.documentElement.style;

/mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !pageYOffset && !location.hash && setTimeout(function () {
  CSS.height = '200%';
  CSS.overflow = 'visible';

  window.scrollTo(0, 1);

  CSS.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  CSS.overflow = 'hidden';
}, 1000);​
```

However I'd recommend extending Scott Jehl's method, which addresses minor Android/iOS Safari scrollTo differences:

https://gist.github.com/scottjehl/1183357

Comment: I updated Scott's gist URL (which was 404), but simply to note that from the comments, it seems like this method does not work anymore (as of 2018)