# How to hide the safari address bar on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide the address bar on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone)

I put all this in the head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

I also put some jquery/javascript code to raise the browser up.. but it doesnt work.. what other solutions are there?!?

```
<script>
    addEventListener("load", function() {
        window.scrollTo(1, 0);
    }, false);    
</script>
```

The above doesn't work either.

Comment: Your code is correct but you need to create a shortcut of your web page. Then, when you click on your shortcut, the address bar will not be shown

Comment: possibly a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone

Comment: i tried to go through the duplicates..and no..it isnt how to hid the address bar..the solution there doesnt work

Comment: @sdespont, that is not what i am looking for..i want to achieve the effect without a shortcut

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd — Not having an answer that works doesn't stop a question being a duplicate. If none of the answers are sufficient, then offer a bounty and/or comment on the existing question.

Comment: who tried to close my question.. I am telling..the scroll 1 pixel up..doesnt work too... and