# Hide address bar onload Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m on a Nexus 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, nexus-7

I am attempting to hide the address bar onload on a Nexus 7 tablet window.scrollTo(0, 1);  Doesn't work or scrolling to an anchors.  Any other tricks to accomplish this?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone
Maybe you just need to add a small padding to your body tag, or height like 101%

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but in my opinion you should try to avoid overriding a browser's default behavior.

Comment: I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone, didn't solve the problem.  Its a recent udpate to chrome that prevents window.scrollTo(0, 1);