# How to hide Safari’s toolbars when orientation changes to landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, landscape

I’ve tried the following approach:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">
```

and

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
setTimeout(scrollTo, 0, 0, 1);
}, false);
```

But it hasn’t worked. Could you advise something on this?

Comment: Did you try this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone

Comment: @Programmer2.0, yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952980/is-it-possible-to-hide-url-bar-in-ios-9-safari-browser-by-using-javascript). Basically make your content higher than viewport and it would become fullscreen (Hiding toolbars) when switching to landscape. Not perfect but usable.