# Is it possible to hide URL bar in iOS 9 (Safari browser) by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios9, single-page-application

I want to hide the URL bar from my single-page application by using JavaScript.

I tried to set bigger height of the 'body' element and then perform:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But it doesn't work. The URL bar is still visible. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iPhone, you can make your content just one pixel higher than the viewport, that will eliminate the navbar.

Working code example: http://pastebin.com/16s8Xvbw

**Caveats:**

- Only works in landscape, and when flipping from portrait to landscape - if user enters the page in landscape, he/she must flip to portrait and back to landscape.
- If the user touches near top / bottom, navbar will re-appear.
- Does not work on iPad at all.

Comment: This does not work for me, can you be more specific?  I modified the meta viewport  content height attribute via JavaScript and no change in address bar...

Comment: I updated the post with some details, hope it helps!

Comment: This solution does not seem to do anything. Tested on ipad mini and iphone 5s.  I have found that the behavior of Safari 9 varies from release to release.  The hide on rotation only occurs on the iphone regardless of the the extra pixel.  I am currently on 9.1(13B143).

Comment: It does not work on iPad at all, I should have mentioned that. Also found a small error in the pastebin (updated). If you go to http://www.quizkey.com/ios on your iPhone and flip to landscape, the navbar stays? (Works on my iPhone 5S with 9.1, 13B143)

Comment: The iPhone behavior  is the default behavior.  When rotated to landscape the nav bar hides by default.  No need to add the 1px...

Comment: I copied the page to quizkey.com/ios2 without the spacer. I can't get rid of the nav bar, can you?

Answer (score 4):

so far it seems it doesn't work on iOS 9, it stopped working after iOS 7.1.

As seen here:

[Impossible to hide navigation bars in Safari iOS 7 for iPhone/iPod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793072/impossible-to-hide-navigation-bars-in-safari-ios-7-for-iphone-ipod-touch?rq=1)