# How to hide mobile address bar on modal open?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there any way to hide mobile address bar when modal open. I need modal hide 100vh but when mobile address bar there, it hides lower portion of modal.

Comment: repetitive question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395561/how-to-hide-a-mobile-browsers-address-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the mobile browser URL bar, then I don't think you can do that, that URL bar is not part of the HTML.