# Hide address and browser footer on mobile jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, mobile-development

Is there any way we can force hide mobile browser's address bar and footer (navigation bar) so all the page content is visible on web app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395561/how-to-hide-a-mobile-browsers-address-bar

Comment: @Shree I tried that and all the solutions found in the internet. Nothing worked. This post seems too old and with the browsers being updated, those method won't work for current scenario

Comment: It's not that old. If the solutions work they work, otherwise they no longer work due to security issues