# What css property will cause the URL bar on Chrome android browser to auto hide?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, mobile-browser

If you go to twitter.com on the Android Chrome browser and scroll up, then the address bar will auto hide itself to make more room for the webpage.

My app used to do this. But now I am not sure what I tweaked to make this no work.

The main `div` of the app is set to `height: 100vh`. And because the address bar does not auto hide, the bottom is clipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a mobile browser's address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395561/how-to-hide-a-mobile-browsers-address-bar)

Comment: Could u share your app or some reproducible code